# ODBC 11-18 won't install on Windows Server 2019

Tags: odbc, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows 2019 box as below

[image]

I have tried installing ODBC 11 upwards but get the same error each time

[image]

Can it be right that the newest ODBC I can install is 10?

Comment: As I mentioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73234789/2029983), the oldest version of ODBC [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-operating-systems) on Windows Server 2019 is 17.3. Though you **really** need to do some upgrades; Windows 2019  release 1809 means you've not updated your server in almost 4 years...